# Proof identity for hypergeometric series 2F1(a,b;c;x)

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

I would like prove the following identity:
$$
_2F_1(a,b;c,x) = \frac{c+(a−b+1)x}{c} {} _2F_1(a+1,b;c+1;x) - \frac{(a+1)(c−b+1)x}{c(c+1)} {} _2F_1(a+2,b;c+2;x).
$$

I've tried this so far:

I know that $y= {} _2F_1(a,b;c,x)$ satisfies the differential equation:
$$
x(1-x)y'' + (c-(a+b+1)x)y' -aby = 0.
$$
If I substitute $y$ in the differential equation, I get:
$$
_2F_1(a,b;c,x) = x(1-x) \dfrac{(a+1)(b+1)}{(c+1)} {} _2F_1(a+2,b+2;c+2,x) +(c-(a+b+1)x)  {}_2F_1(a+1,b+1;c+1,x)
$$

I was thinking of using Pfaff/Euler's identity, which says that

$$
_2F_1(a,b;c;x) = (1-x)^{-a} {} _2F_1 (a, c-b;c ; \dfrac{x}{x-1}) = (1-x)^{c-a-b} {} _2F_1 (c-a, c-b;c ; x).
$$

However, from here on I don't know what to do. Can someone give a hint / a solution?

Comment: Just use the definition of the ${}_2F_1$. Expand everything as power series in $x$ and identify the coefficients.

Answer (score 5):

There are fifteen [Gauss' contiguous relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Gauss%27_contiguous_relations) for functions $F(a, b ; c ; z)$, $F(a \pm 1, b ; c ; z), F(a, b \pm 1, c ; z)$, and $F(a, b ; c \pm 1 ; z)$, see *Erdélyi A. et al. Higher transcendental functions. Vol. I, sec. 2.8, (31)-(45).* And all possible three-term identities follow from these fifteen step by step.